# Dynamically loaded ASP.NET user control fails to initialize

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, user-controls

I am using an ASP.NET user control to encapsulate some functionality in my app. I am aware that the Page_Load handler in the control runs after the Page_Load handler in the page hosting it, so that I cannot initialize the control from the host page's Page_Load, which is annoying. I am using Page_LoadComplete on the host page to do this, and it works fine when the control is statically added to the page's HTML at design time.

However, when I try to load the control dynamically at run time, things go wrong. I successfully instantiate the control and add it to a Panel in my page. I add it to a collection so that initialization is postponed until Page_LoadComplete as in the previous case. When the code in Page_LoadComplete tries to initialize the control, however, it fails because, apparently, the control has not loaded yet. Specifically, I find that when the control's Page_Load is triggered (right after the host page's Page_Load), its local fields have not been initialized yet. For example, fields mapping the sub-controls in the user control are still null, as are other fields that I have added. You may argue that the fields I have added should be initialized by me, but the fields that map sub-controls should have been initialized before Page_Load runs, right?

Is this the expected behaviour? If so, what can I do to initialize my control properly when dynamically loading? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[event diagram](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC386473.png)

Try adding the controls in the PreInit stage so that the controls are there during the init stage and available before the processing of the postback data

Comment: I've tried, and the problem stays the same. I have solved the issue by using statically-declared controls in my HTML, and deferring initialization to Page_LoadComplete.